# Рекурсивная выборка

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица вида:

```
id int not null
parent int null
...
```

Где parent указывает на id родителя.
Необходимо по заданному id получить список всех потомков до самого последнего.
Вроде-бы задача распространенная, есть ли готовые решения или нужно изобретать свое?

СУБД MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with Q as(
 select * from Tab where parent=10
 union all
 select p.* from Tab p, Q
  where p.parent=Q.id
)
select * from Q
```

Примерно так. Первая часть перед `union all` должна выбрать "затравочные" записи, с которых надо начинать выборку. Вторая часть - рекурсивная, для всех записей выбранный первой частью или ей самой находит следующие

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT parentName 
FROM parentTable AS p 
JOIN yourTable AS y ON y.parentId = p.parentId
;
```

Вот вариант если я Вас правильно понял

Comment: Как я понял - количество потомков не известно.

Comment: Нет, нужно получить также потомков всех потомков, итд.