# Рекурсивный запрос к дереву

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Требуется создать представление (*View*) к таблице с древовидной структурой (*id*, *parent_id*), обращаясь к которой можно будет получить:

- все элементы
- все дочерние элементы требуемого элемента (передаем *id*)
- все родительские элементы требуемого элемента до наивысшего уровня (передаем *id*)

Использовать `hierarchyid` не предлагать, *MS SQL Server 2005* его не поддерживает. :(

Использовать хранимую процедуру не предлагать (это должно быть именно представление, к которому я бы мог обратиться из фильтра с оператором IN или приджойнить его без создания временной таблицы)

Данные ограничения я не из вредности накладываю. Просто архитектура проекта очень специфическая.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175972(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: А это подходит  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503409/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0/503413#503413

Comment: Обычно это не через представления делается, а через табличные функции с параметром.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я умею гуглить... и даже не нуб в запросах. Но я не могу придумать такую вьюху, которая удовлетворит требованиям

Comment: @iRumba А почему это должна быть вьюха. Вы вьюхе параметр не передадите. а стартовый id это именно параметр, так что как я указал выше с помощью CTE и это единственный путь

Comment: @i-one, да, функции я почему то даже не рассматривал. Не думал, что  конструкция `SELECT * FROM MyFunction()` будет работать :D. Жаль только, что функцию не проиндексировать... или можно?

Comment: @iRumba, функцию не проиндексировать, но таблицу-дерево проиндексировать не помешает, чтобы рекурсивные запросы к ней побыстрее отрабатывали

Comment: @i-one, само собой, но если джойнить ее к запросу, боюсь, получится запорожец )

Comment: @iRumba, нужно проверять, конечно, всякое может быть (в зависимости от данных и запросов).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имеется таблица-дерево, например:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (ID int not NULL, ParentID int NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
INSERT INTO tree (ID, ParentID) VALUES
    (1, NULL),
        (2, 1),
            (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2),
        (3, 1),
            (7, 3), (8, 3), (9, 3), (10, 3);
```

и при работе с ней намечается много мест, требующих рекурсивного кода, то для удобства рекомендую завести две табличных функции.

Что-то наподобие

```
CREATE FUNCTION treeItemAncestors
(
    @itemID int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    WITH cte(ID, ParentID)
    AS
    (
        SELECT ID, ParentID
        FROM tree
        WHERE ID = @itemID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t.ID, t.ParentID
        FROM tree t
            JOIN cte ON cte.ParentID = t.ID
    )
    SELECT ID
    FROM cte
GO
```

и

```
CREATE FUNCTION treeItemDescendants
(
    @itemID int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    WITH cte(ParentID, ID)
    AS
    (
        SELECT ParentID, ID
        FROM tree
        WHERE ID = @itemID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t.ParentID, t.ID
        FROM tree t
            JOIN cte ON cte.ID = t.ParentID
    )
    SELECT ID
    FROM cte
GO
```

Я их назвал *descendants* и *ancestors*, но они также возвращают и сам узел, который передаётся параметром (исходя из моей практики чаще всего именно это и требуется, но если нужно, можно его исключить). Также у меня они возвращают только список ID. Если нужны и другие столбцы, то нужно их добавить в `cte` и в результирующий `select`.

Для того, чтобы `treeItemAncestors` хорошо работала в данном случае достаточно имеющегося кластерного первичного ключа.

Для хорошей работы `treeItemDescendants` желательно добавить индекс по `ParentID`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tree_ParentID ON tree (ParentID) INCLUDE (ID);
```

Другие поля, если они есть и необходимы, также можно занести в `include`.

Далее можно с ними работать, например:

```
SELECT ID
FROM treeItemAncestors(10);
```

или

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
FROM (VALUES (6), (9)) idlist(id)
    CROSS APPLY treeItemAncestors(idlist.id) a;
```

или

```
DELETE t
FROM tree t
    join treeItemDescendants(3) d on d.ID = t.ID;
```

и т.п.

Comment: **Для i-one** Как перевести запросиз вашего примера
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
FROM (VALUES (6), (9)) idlist(id) CROSS APPLY treeItemAncestors(idlist.id) a; применительно к MS SQL 2005/ Заранее благодарен
Юрий

Comment: @JuriShutenko, в SqlServer 2005 ещё не было VALUES, поэтому вместо `(VALUES (6), (9)) idlist(id)` нужно использовать `(SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 9) idlist(id)`.