# Нужно получить всех родителей одним запросом

Tags: sql

У нас есть база:

```
ARTICLE_________
ID | CATEGORY_ID

CATEGORY_______
ID | PARENT_ID
```

Нужно достать категории статей + их родительские категории в одном запросе, пока получилось только категории новостей:

```
LEFT JOIN `article` ON `article`.`category_id` = `category`.`id`
```

Comment: Что значит "+ их родительские категории" ? Их же может быть много, каким образом они должны быть показаны в выводе ? Какая именно у вас СУБД ? В общем случае потребуется рекурсивный запрос или его имитация и в разных СУБД это решается совершенно по разному

Comment: да, много, у каждой категории она есть. Цель: массив arr[parent_id] = categories

Comment: Массив вы никак не получите. Нарисуйте строго прямоугольную таблицу как БД должна вернуть данные. Думаю для каждого родителя нужна отдельная строка. А массив уже соберете на клиенте. И вы так и не сказали какая БД у вас. Если вдруг mysql и она не 8 версии, то вообще забудьте, не умеет она так (ну либо будете извращаться как то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634545/194569). А если все таки 8 или другая СУБД - то вроде такого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503413/194569